# Remove html tags using gsub in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use gsub to remove html tags from a text string. I can remove the first part and not the end tag `</a>` . Below is the code which I have tried.

```
url = "https://www.w3schools.com"
text1 = paste0("<a href='", url, "'>", url, "</a>")
gsub("<([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)(.[^>]*)>([.^<]*)", "\\3", text1)
```

The output I get is

```
[1] "https://www.w3schools.com</a>"
```

Comment: `gsub("<[^>]*>","", paste(text1, collapse=""))`

Comment: `gsub("<.*?>", "", text1)` from the link.